# Manually remove first image in wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have 18,000+ wordpress posts where I was using a function to hide the first image in posts, but I don't want to do that anymore. I would like to use just the featured image and that's it, without having to insert a featured image in the post just to hide it (using that function).

I was thinking about just manually removing everything in a text editor but can't tell which one to remove since it's there2 or 3 times. example:

```
 INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES(16179, 88, '2009-05-28 08:32:47', '2009-05-28 12:32:47', '<img src="http://localhost/readjunk/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum.jpg" alt="news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum" title="news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum" width="450" height="250" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-16180" />\r\nTaking Back Sunday will be streaming New Again in its entirety on their <a href="http://www.myspace.com/takingbacksunday">MySpace page</a> on Thursday May 28th and Friday May 29th.  New Again officially hits stores next Tuesday, June 2nd.\r\n<!--more-->\r\n\r\nTaking Back Sunday will <a href="http://localhost/readjunk/news/music/blink-182-reunite-and-announce-summer-tour/">be touring on select dates</a> with Blink 182. Check out their music video for Sink Into Me <a href="http://localhost/readjunk/media/music-video-taking-back-sunday-sink-into-me/">here</a>.\r\n\r\nFor more info visit:  <a href="http://www.takingbacksunday.com">www.takingbacksunday.com</a>\r\n', 'MySpace hosting Taking Back Sunday "New Again" listening party tonight and Friday', 0, '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', 'myspace-hosting-taking-back-sunday-new-again-listening-party-tonight-and-friday', '', '', '2009-05-28 08:32:47', '2009-05-28 12:32:47', '', 0, 'http://localhost/readjunk/?p=16179', 0, 'post', '', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES(16180, 88, '2009-05-28 08:28:27', '2009-05-28 12:28:27', '', 'news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum', 0, '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum', '', '', '2009-05-28 08:28:27', '2009-05-28 12:28:27', '', 16179, 'http://localhost/readjunk/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum.jpg', 0, 'attachment', 'image/jpeg', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES(16181, 88, '2009-05-28 08:32:36', '2009-05-28 12:32:36', '<img src="http://localhost/readjunk/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum.jpg" alt="news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum" title="news_0509_takingbacksundayalbum" width="450" height="250" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-16180" />\nTaking Back Sunday will be streaming New Again in its entirety on their <a href="http://www.myspace.com/takingbacksunday">MySpace page</a> on Thursday May 28th and Friday May 29th.  New Again officially hits stores next Tuesday, June 2nd.\n<!--more-->\n\nTaking Back Sunday will <a href="http://localhost/readjunk/news/music/blink-182-reunite-and-announce-summer-tour/">be touring on select dates</a> with Blink 182. Check out their music video for Sink Into Me <a href="http://localhost/readjunk/media/music-video-taking-back-sunday-sink-into-me/">here</a>.\n\nFor more info visit:  <a href="http://www.takingbacksunday.com">www.takingbacksunday.com</a>\n', 'MySpace hosting Taking Back Sunday "New Again" listening party tonight and Friday', 0, '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', '16179-revision', '', '', '2009-05-28 08:32:36', '2009-05-28 12:32:36', '', 16179, 'http://localhost/readjunk/uncategorized/16179-revision/', 0, 'revision', '', 0, NULL);
```

is it just both img tags or just the first line?

Comment: well the ids look like 16179 and up. Are you asking how to manually do a delete based on id's? Are there other tables that doing such would forbid it or screw them up?

Comment: yeah not sure. I'm in wp_posts so not sure why there's 2 or 3 of the same posts in there. i'm using a featured image plugin that uses the first image in post, so maybe that's what creating an extra id? not a programmer so not sure. i want to delete the image in a post so not sure if i should try deleting the second one since the first one might be the attachment?

Comment: The first one is the post, the second is the attachment and the third one is a revision. You can see the `post_type` in the insert arguments, it's the 4th from last argument `'post'`, `'attachment'`, `'revision'`. You don't need to touch the attachment or revision, potentially you could delete all of the revisions.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you posted 3 different INSERT statements that represent the initial post (with a `post_status` of "publish"), the next line is the image that was uploaded to the Media Gallery (with a `post_type` of `attachment`) and the third represents an edit to the initial post (with a `post_status` of "inherit")

Rather than using a text editor I would recommend doing this programmatically. You could loop through all of your posts and create a new edit using the WordPress API, or you could just update the most recent post with the new `post_content`.

You should be able to use a regular expression to remove the first image in your content. Something like:

```
$post->post_content = preg_replace( "~^[^>]*>~", "", $post->content );
```

Check out the regex description at Regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/jP9vZ6/1

Comment: thanks, how do I go about using that? put in function.php?

Comment: You could do it in functions.php, or you can use the Developer/Debug Bar/Debug Bar Console plugins to run arbitrary PHP from the browser. Once installed click Debug on the top right, then Console on the left. Definitely do this on a non-production server :)